# C# list and count all usages of class properties

Tags: c#, class, properties, code-analysis

I have several classes in my solution with a lot of properties.
Now I would like to write a piece of code that can output a list with following information

- class
- class property
- usages of class property in solution

Is there a clever way to do that?
(I'm aware how to list a classes properties, but how do I get the properties that are used and their counts?)

Comment: Before you write a code analyzer (not a trivial task), have you looked for any tools that can do this for you?

Comment: have you tried ildasm?

Comment: Also note that reflection code bypasses any usage counts, so anything you come up with is not reliable.

Comment: i read about Rosyln for now (have to check in detail if its possible to do this), however since its implemented in most of the IDEs I thought there might be a nice way to implement this... I was not aware of the reflection issue actually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the tool NDepend you can [write a code query](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/query-code-with-csharp-linq) similar to this one.

```
            // Adjust this to match exactly the time you want
            // like for example ... WithNameLike("regex")
let types = Application.Namespaces.WithName("Nop.Core").ChildTypes()

let properties = (from t1 in types
   from m in t1.Methods
   where !m.IsStatic && m.IsPropertyGetter || m.IsPropertySetter
   select m)

from prop in properties
select new { prop, prop.MethodsCallingMe }
```

You can then browse the query result and for each property get the count and list of usage thanks to `prop.MethodsCallingMe`:

[image: ndepend code query result]

You then get various facility to export some or all elements in the query result to a live [dependency graph](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) to better visualize the dependencies:

[image: ndepend code query result exported to a dependency graph]

You can [download full featured trial here](https://www.ndepend.com/download).

*Disclaimer: I work at NDepend*

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I am impressed by this powerful tool, solves my task for now with the 14-day trial!